# How to use ForkJoin for POST Method in angular

Tags: angular, fork-join

Is it possible to use ForkJoin for post methods? that too with the use of service?

I want to send multiple post requests at a time using ForkJoin in Angular.

this is the code I have for get methods as per this reference: https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-multiple-http-requests-with-rxjs

```
let character = this.http.get('https://swapi.co/api/people/1');
    let characterHomeworld = this.http.get('http://swapi.co/api/planets/1');

    forkJoin([character, characterHomeworld]).subscribe(results => {
      // results[0] is our character
      // results[1] is our character homeworld
      results[0].homeworld = results[1];
      this.loadedCharacter = results[0];
    });
```

is it possible use POST methods with set of parameters?

Editing question here:

I have added code like below:

```
fetch_details(res){
var requests_list = [];
if(res == 1){
let request = this.http.post('BankDetailsUpdate', bank_params );
        requests_list.push(request);
}
if(res == 2){
let request = this.http.post('PersonalDetailsUpdate', bank_params );
        requests_list.push(request);
}

 this.save_details(requests_list);
}

save_details(requests_list){
          if(this.rejectedDetailsForm.valid){
            forkJoin(requests_list).subscribe(results => {
              console.log(results, "results");
            },
            error => console.log("Error: ", error),
            () =>{
     });
     }
    }
```

I am getting below error:

```
Error:  TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
```

what I am missing here? Can you please help?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes it's possible. As long as it's an observable, it can be added to the forkjoin array.

Comment: I think yes, you should give it a try

Comment: can I use service like apiservice.savedata() instead of this. http.post()

Comment: I have updated question, can you please check and help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake: in observable the values are not JSON Object. I have converted to JSON Object, then its working fine now.